# .html doesn't take stylesheets class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have scouted the net, and maybe I am asking or searching the wrong way, but I can't seem to find a solution to this.

When I either do .html() or .append() I don't seem to get the stylesheets styles into the new html?

Here is what i am doing:

```
$.post( "updatepassword.php", { 
                new_pass: true, 
                password1: $(form).find('#password1').val(),
                password2: $(form).find('#password2').val() }).done(function( data ) {

    if(data == "success"){
        show_loading_bar({
            delay: .5,
            pct: 100,
            finish: function(){
                $(".modal-header").append('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>');
                $(".modal-body").html("Yes...");
                $(".modal-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>');
            }
        });
    } else {
        toastr.error("Error!", opts);
        $(form).find('#password1').select();
    }

});
```

All the classes is not taking into the new html?!? is this an bug or am I missing something here?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You have no *stylesheet styles* in the example shown. Do you mean your classes are not adding?

Comment: Yes, classes are not adding. The stylesheets is already loaded in my page.

Comment: Those few lines work fine by themselves: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bd5fkh3j/ Looks like the `finish:` event is not being called.

Comment: No, the finish event is being called, I do get the elements into my html, but just not with the classes.

Comment: That makes no sense. There must be something else interfering with the classes as that code is correct (as the JSFiddle showed).

Comment: can we please swap the quotes for modal header and modal footer append and html statements? you know double quotes wrapping single quotes and not the other way round. yes.

Comment: @pjp: That is a bad idea as standard HTML attributes *should* be double-quoted (even though most browsers allow either single or double).

Comment: There is no *should* - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2... style dependent. i like single wrapped in double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach to this problem (and easier to maintain!) might be to output these elements as part of your HTML, and then toggle their visibility (either by unsetting a class, or using $.show/$.hide).

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsb1t8na/

html:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body hidden">
    Yes...
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white hidden" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion :-)